# asp-action and asp-controller executes post method after reedirects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I use from asp-action in order to logout action as:

```
<form asp-action="Logoff" asp-controller="Account">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-link dropdown-item">
        <i class="mdi mdi-logout font-size-16 align-middle me-1"></i> 
        Logout
    </button>
</form>
```

So I want to use the same to redirect to a new view, that view has a  inside it and the controller has a `HttpPost`, so when I click on it executes the post method, is there a way to avoid the execution of HttpPost method and still using asp-actions?

I change the button type to button, but it do anything when it's clicked

Comment: Log-off forms **should** be `POST` though as it's a HTTP request that will have side-effects (i.e. terminating a user's session), whereas `GET` requests should only be for "safe" requests that simply retrieve data/pages/etc without any massive side-effects. Anyway, what problem are you having, _specifically_?

Comment: I do not want to execute the POST method after asp-action is clicked, I just want to reedirect to the view @Dai

Comment: Please post the sequence of HTTP requests made by your browser, and please point out the undesired requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add `method="get"` into the form,so that when you click on it executes the get request:

```
<form method="get" asp-action="Logoff" asp-controller="Account">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-link dropdown-item">
        <i class="mdi mdi-logout font-size-16 align-middle me-1"></i> 
        Logout
    </button>
</form>
```